# CSS animation not always starting in iOS 8 Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari, css-animations

I've made a slideshow that works by putting three inline blocks next to each other (all with the same background-image) within a slideshow container, and using translateX to move that container 33% of the way to the left/right, before looping. The three inline blocks pretty much ensures it will always look continuous and you never see a seam at the each of your screen.

The slideshow is placed into another container of its own, typical width, and overflow: hidden is used to crop the long photo strip and prevent it from stretching your browser window.

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slideshow {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

#about-slideshow {
    right: 0;
    -webkit-animation: slideshow-right 10s linear infinite;
    animation: slideshow-right 10s linear infinite;
}
#about-slideshow .slide {
    width: 964px;
    background: url('http://simplegrid.cochranesupply.com/images/slideshow-a.jpg') 0 0 repeat-x;
    background-size: 101%;
}

/* the animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideshow-right {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(33.33333333333%);
    }
}
@keyframes slideshow-right {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to { 
        transform: translateX(33.33333333333%);
    }
}
```

**My problem:** After looking at it thoroughly on an iPhone 5S and iPhone 6 Plus, it seems to not start sometimes. It'll just sit there. Maybe glitch out after a while. If I continue to refresh, it will sometimes run, and sometimes not. Seems completely inconsistent.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Seems pretty simple.

Here's a CodePen that I've confirmed displays the issue on iOS Safari: http://codepen.io/arickle/pen/pvGJBM

Here's a full screen view to pull up on an iOS device for testing (remember, keep refreshing until it stops--you don't have to refresh particularly fast or anything): http://codepen.io/arickle/full/pvGJBM/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, I appear to have stumbled upon a workaround at least. Apparently, if mobile Safari hiccups on anything during load, or can't keep up, or *something*, it won't start the animation. My solution was simply to delay the animation by 0.1s. This gives the browser enough time to get everything loaded and then start the animation, every time.

```
-webkit-animation: slideshow-right 10s 0.1s linear infinite;
```

Silly.

Comment: Works amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case (`Safari Version 15.4`), the solution to add a small (`0.1s`) animation delay also worked.

```
animation: slide 37.5s cubic-bezier(0.83, 0, 0.17, 1) 0.1s infinite;
```